# Sending email in php?

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I am quite new to PHP and am experimenting with an online ordering website in php. I have come across a problem when trying to send a confirmation email using a 'cc'.

Every time an order is processed, the order always sends to the 'CC' address specified but does not send to the 'TO'. Most likely due to an error in my code.

In the email confirmation received, it only displays the from section and the 'to' section is empty as demonstrated below:

```
From: Business@business.co.uk
To: *This space is empty*
CC: orders@business.co.uk
```

Can anyone help to point out where I am going wrong? I have attached the code below.

```
//Code to retreive customer email
 $query  = "SELECT od_email 
 FROM tbl_order";
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 

//THIS IS THE EMAIL SENT TO THE CUSTOMER and the restaurant
//define the receiver of the email
$_SESSION['od_email'] = $data['od_email'];
$sendto = $_SESSION['od_email'];
//define the subject of the email
$subject = 'Order Confirmation | Ref No for Order: '.  $_SESSION['orderId']; //this session function works properly
//define the message to be sent. Each line should be separated with \n
$message = 'test';
//Who the message is from
$from = "business@business.co.uk";
$cc = "orders@business.co.uk";
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From:" . $from . "\r\n";
//bcc header going to the restaurant
$headers .= "cc:" . $cc . "\r\n";
//send the email
$mail_sent = @mail( $sendto, $subject, $message, $headers );




unset($_SESSION['od_email']);
```

What I need for it to show is:

```
From: **business@business.co.uk**
To: **$_SESSION['od_email'];**
CC: **orders@business.co.uk**
```

Thanks in advance for any help given

Comment: Are you sure that $_SESSION['od_email'] has a value? What do you get if you `var_dump($_SESSION['od_email'])`?

Comment: Same thing happens when this is done. I am sure it does have a value. Every section in the database of this field has a valid test email address. However, I want it to pick the email address of the order customers order after he has placed the order. This is why I have assumed I use the session function.

Comment: I'm still not sure why you're setting $_SESSION['od_email'] and then unsetting it at the end. Still, it would seem that the most likely problem here is that $sendto (and $_SESSION['od_email']) is NULL or blank. `exit($sendto);` before `mail()` should print it's value. Also, it seems like your query should look like this: "SELECT od_email FROM tbl_order WHERE id=$_SESSION['orderId']" so that you don't select every row.

Comment: How would you set the $_SESSION['od_email']? Because I just realised that it is not set.
Basically I need to retrieve the last order in the session. That is why I have set the $_SESSION['od_email']. 
Is there an easier way to get this information from the database?

Comment: You'll have to solve the problem in parts. The first part will be to refine your SQL query.  If you have command line access to mysql, try using that to see what kind of results the query gives. I'm guessing you will need to restrict your query using a "WHERE" clause. It's giving you every email in the table currently, or maybe none at all. Once you have the correct query, the rest of the code ought to work. If you can narrow down your issue, then I can work on a full answer for you.

Comment: Ok, one way could be to select the last order processed processed? But how could I represent that as an SQL query?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT od_email
FROM tbl_order
BY od_id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or mysql_error();

//define the receiver of the email

$to = $result;

Comment: Ok, the above sql statement works and it gets the last ordered email address. But how to I convert this into the "TO" section? The way I have shown it above is '$to = $result'; but that did not work.

Comment: You'll need to fetch the data from the MySQL result:
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$to = $row[0];

Comment: just one question, why put a 0 in the $row[0];??? Just so that I can understand why it worked

Comment: mysql_fetch_row returns an array of your results, so the [0] gives you the first (and only) element returned. Have a look at [the doco](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php 
session_start();
include 'connect.php';

error_reporting( error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE);

 $message=$_POST['message'];
 $cc=$_POST['ccemail'];
 $bcc=$_POST['bccemail'];
 $emailid=$_POST['email'];
// $file=$_GET['file'];


$file=$_FILES['forwarded_file']['name'];
        $dest="admin/$file";
        $src=$_FILES['forwarded_file']['tmp_name'];

$run=mysql_query("SELECT od_email 
 FROM tbl_order");

 include 'classes/class.phpmailer.php';
 $mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
 $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
 $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
 $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
 $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
 $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
 $mail->Port = 465; // 587
 $mail->IsHTML(true);
 $mail->Username = "business@business.co.uk";
 $mail->Password = "******"; //Don't reveal password with others
 $mail->SetFrom("business@business.co.uk");
 $mail->Subject  = "Test";
 $mail->Body ="Test";

$mail->AddAddress($emailid);
$mail->AddCC($cc);
$mail->AddBCC($bcc);

if (isset($_FILES['$file']) &&
    $_FILES['$file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['$file']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['$file']['name']);
}

$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['forwarded_file']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['forwarded_file']['name']);
 if(!$mail->Send())
 {
  "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  echo "<script>alert('Not Send Successfully');document.location='../abc.php'</script>";
 }
 else
 {
 echo "Message has been sent";
echo "<script>alert('Send Successfully');document.location='../abc.php'</script>";
 }

?>
```

Here you can also add attachments if any.The class.phpmailer.php is the library added and the coonect.php is the connection file to connect to the database.you can also view the output at the following [link](http://yogeshprajapati.site88.net/sms_demo/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the question has been answered in the comments - but in full:

The `$_SESSION['od_email']` variable wasn't being populated, therefore the To address is left empty.

The solution was to add a query to get the username from the most recent order:

```
$sql = "SELECT od_email FROM tbl_order BY od_id DESC LIMIT 1"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql) or mysql_error(); 

//define the receiver of the email 
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result); 
$to = $row[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using session. and you have not started any session before using it.

start session. add this to top of your page

```
session_start();
```